# "The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory cannot be resolved." error message in selenium script

Tags: android, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jar, appium

I'm trying to build a testing framework for an android application using selenium webdriver on eclipse and Appium. I'm not using Maven. The initial script to launch the app is as follows:

```js
package executionEngine;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class DriverScript {
 
 public static AndroidDriver driver = null;
 


 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  

  File app = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\BP_QASTG.apk");
  
  // Created object of DesiredCapabilities class.
  
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");

    // Set android deviceName desired capability. Set your device name.
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Tab A");


    // Set android VERSION desired capability. Set your mobile device's OS version.
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.2");

    // Set android platformName desired capability. It's Android in our case here.
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

    // Set android appPackage desired capability. It is

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.rivigo.zoombp.rivigozoombpapp");

    // Set android appActivity desired capability. It is

    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.rivigo.zoombp.rivigozoombpapp.activity.Activity.RivigoHomeActivity");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

    // Set appium server address and port number in URL string.
    //AndroidDriver  driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
   driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
   //driver = (AndroidDriver)((new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities));        
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }

}
```

**In the above code, the line where I declare the URL is marked in RED and hovering over it shows me this message: "The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"**

I have seen many answers asking to add required jar files; but I'm sure I have added all the jar files required. It would be great if anyone can point out the particular jar file I might have missed,if indeed that is the issue, so that I can download and add it separately.

I have seen other answers asking to remove and re-add the JRE system library or close and repair the project, etc. which did not work for me.

I have tried with eclipse-neon and eclipse-mars versions also.
Please ask for any details you need,

I'm blocked here for quite sometime,
help on this would be appreciated,

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: what jar are you using for selenium? i mean the version

Comment: selenium 2.43.0...

Comment: check my answer on this post, which resolved the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235272/appium-throws-an-error-because-of-the-driver/59612535#59612535

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar exception while working on automation framework which was built to serve as a base framework for UI (Mobile and Web) and AIP automation. Technologies which I was using included selenium web driver and appium for UI and Mobile automation. This was maven project and I ended up having bunch of dependencies. When I spent a hell lot time investigating my exceptions, root cause I found was dependency conflict because there were lot of dependencies which included different version of same artifact. In this case dependency in conflict was "com.squareup.okhttp3" which i had defined explicitly in my POM and same dependency is part of selenium-java as well. Please try following solution and hopefully that should work:

**Exception:**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/ConnectionPool
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient$Factory.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault(HttpClient.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<clinit>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:47)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:95)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at nz.co.flexicards.automation.framework.common.Common.BaseMobile.main(BaseMobile.java:62)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.ConnectionPool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Solution:**

1. I removed the explicit dependency for okhttp3 from POM.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

2. Moved java-client (appium-io) dependency on top in dependency list in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code before creating the driver object.
`System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "apache");`

Answer (score 0):

This requires

> [commons-validator.jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/download_validator.cgi)

which has set of methods to do common http and other user requests and validations.

And kindly update your selenium jar as 2.5x or more have come now

Comment: Even this solution didn't work; but the issue got solved though. I will answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved when I followed below steps,

- Created a new project
- Added Selenium (2.53.1), gson (2.2.4-sources) and javaclient(4.0.0) jars

Previously I added different version of java client jar; I did not add any gson jar before.
Maybe these changes solved my problem. (I'm not sure though)

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured today.

I just switched the version of java-client from 5.0.0 to 1.2.1, and found the problem solved.

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below maven dependency to your pom.xml to resolve the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have problem with java-client jar.

After changing java-client-7.0.0 version to java-client-3.2.0 my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the externals libraries that I had, and then I add **java-client/7.0.0.**
It has anything that you need, then my project worked.

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0/source-code

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error text "Unknown HttpClient factory netty" when you run your tests, using appium 2.0 and selenium 4+. You can check your dependecy selelnium-java maven. I updated to the latest version and it works

Answer (score -1):

Adding "selenium-remote-driver" solved the problem

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer please?

Answer (score -1):

appium , selenium, okhttp alltogether happily, please check my answer :
[Appium throws an error because of the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235272/appium-throws-an-error-because-of-the-driver/59612535#59612535)