# Appium throws an error because of the driver

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am trying to run automated test with appium, but I always get the following error :

```
FAILED: f
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
```

I've noticed that if I delete everything from the driver declaration to the bottom, the test is successful. Here is my code :

```
package test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class FirstTest {
  @Test
  public void f() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        new DesiredCapabilities();
        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.CHROME);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME , Platform.ANDROID);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "K6T6R16C01001259"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "7.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");


        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't need appPackage and appActivity for browser testing with appium. Why did you specify platformName 2 times?

Comment: Probably by mistake. I am new in this.

Comment: How are you running the test ?

Comment: u r giving browser.type && appPackage,launchable activity both , It should be only one to be used

Comment: @SameerArora I am using TestNG. I have enabled USB debugging and the device is connected and unlocked with no running app.

Comment: @AmitJain I tried with just one of each and I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Solved it on my own. I converted the project into maven one and it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the the same problem on a dual appium + selenium project, which had been working fine.
It stopped to work with the same exception the day I upgraded intellij... 
Somehow a duplicate dependency was inserted into the pom.xml.
 (existing org.seleniumhq.selenium in 3.141.59 and 3.6. version), of which I was not aware, which I suspect was introduced by the install and not by some missed move of me.
So the source of the error was coming from this duplicate org.seleniumhq.selenium 3.6.
(not compatible with either Appium 7.0.2 or com.squareup.okhttp3 or both...).

Summary :

1. remove the org.seleniumhq.selenium 3.6 duplicate dependency,
2. empty the "target" directory
3. run a "maven clean" task.

Then all was back up to work. 
so that appium 7.0.2, selenium 3.141.59 and com.squareup.okhttp3 3.11.0 were all doing fine together again.